# Distribution of Spanish speakers regarding 's' and 'c' pronunciation

Tags: españa, pronunciación, ceceo-seseo

We know that following groups of syllables

1. se, si, sa, so, su
2. ce, ci, za, zo, zu

can be pronunced in 3 different ways:

| Context | distinción | seseo | ceceo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "s" + vowel | /s/ | /s/ | /θ/ |
| "c/z" + vowel | /θ/ | /s/ | /θ/ |

The question is: approximately how many people in Spain use each of these pronunciations?

I don't ask for Latin America because I know they use "seseo".

Comment: This appears to be nearly the same question as [How is the letter 's' pronounced in Spain?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-is-the-letter-s-pronounced-in-spain). As that one is older and has more answers, I'm closing this is favor of that—but *please* feel free to add the details from this question there.

Comment: @Dori I'm not asking the same thing and this is much more detailed (for ex. I'm not talking only about 's'). Anyway you have the chance to merge the 2 questions and their answers as an admin.

Comment: The other question is extremely confusingly named, and posed. Without a bunch of fixing I don't think it makes a good "master" question to redirect other closed dupes to in its current state.

Comment: The other question asks about 's' in Spain, it does not worry about the pronounciation of z/c.  These are very different questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The images in [this](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seseo) wikipedia page outline the areas of the Spanish speaking world which have predominance of *seseo / ceceo / distinción*:

| Region | Map |
| --- | --- |
| [Los países hispanos](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Seseo-ceceo-distinci%C3%B3n_en_el_espa%C3%B1ol.png) | [image: Los países hispanos] |
| [España (salvo Canarias)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ceceo-seseo-distinci%C3%B3n_en_el_espa%C3%B1ol_de_Europa.png) | [image: España (salvo Canarias)] |
| [Andalucía](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Andaluc%C3%ADa_ceceante_y_seseante.svg) | [image: Andalucía] |
| [Galicia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Seseo_idioma_gallego.png) | [image: Galicia] [image: Galicia key] |

Comment: ¿Y cuáles áreas tiene qué forma de hablar?  Es mejor resumir el contenido de los enlaces.  Además, ¿qué nos cuentas del español africano?

Comment: He insertado las imágenes en el comentario. *El español africano* se detalla en la primera imagen.

Answer (score 4):

**Seseo** - used entirely in the Canary Islands and rarely in Andalusia.

**Ceceo** - can be often found in western and southern Andalusia.

You can safely say that in the rest of the Spain speakers have **distinción**:

- `/s/` *"s"*
- `/θ/` *"z"* & soft *"c"*

Comment: "Correctly" distinguished?  What makes one way correct over another?

Comment: I meant: they pronounce each sound as it is supposed to be: θ for c/z, s for s.

Comment: This seems to answer a specific question I also wanted to ask that doesn't seem to be clearly addressed in the so-called duplicate.

Comment: Note that seseo exists in Galicia in some parts as well