# ¿Por qué la diferencia entre s y z/c solo se da en España?

Tags: pronunciación, ceceo-seseo

La pronunciación en el centro y el norte de España, como sabemos, pronuncia la "ce" y la "zeta" en forma diferente a la "ese" que es el único sonido que se utiliza para estas tres letras en hispanoamérica. ¿Cual es la causa?

Comment: Eso no es ceceo :) Ceceo es pronunciar "ese" y "zeta" como /θ/ (como en inglés "thin"). Por ejemplo, "casa" y "caza" se pronuncian igual como /kaθa/. A lo que tú te refieres y explicas muy bien, es decir "casa" y "caza" de forma distinta: /kasa/ y /kaθa/. Por otro lado, piensa que para mí (yo hago justo lo que tú preguntas) es curioso el seseo, es decir, pronunciar todo como "ese" ;)

Comment: También we encuentra la distinción en el español africano.

Comment: es bueno saber que aùn hay personas que nos preocupamos por la evolución de nuestra lengua.

Comment: Relacionado: [Distribution of Spanish speakers regarding 's' and 'c' pronunciation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26/1674)

Answer (score 23):

Como ha aclarado JolSauron, en el centro y norte de España no hay ceceo, sino el dialecto castellano puro y duro, que pronuncia  /s/ o /θ/ según esté en el español escrito la "s" o la "z" (o la "c" cuando tiene sonido "z" en "ce" y"ci"), y que en España se ha considerado mucho tiempo, y de hecho se considera, el español "culto", "correcto" u "ortodoxo".

El ceceo es pronunciar las "s" como si fuera una "z"  de "zapato" tal como la pronunciaría un castellano, y es típico del dialecto andaluz, concretamente de ciertas zonas del suroeste de Andalucía, por ejemplo de Jerez de la Frontera, aunque dicen que hay también algunas poblaciones ceceantes en Hispanoamérica.

Sin embargo, por el centro de Andalucía, sobre todo en Córdoba, y en  mayor o menor medida por el resto de Andalucía y sur de España,  lo que predomina es el seseo, que es justo lo contrario (la "z" castellana de "zapato" se pronuncia como "s"), lo mismo que sucede en el Nuevo Mundo (Nuevo sólo para los europeos que no vivían allí, obviamente).

En España, al margen de ciertos seseos locales por influencia de una segunda lengua (como el gallego y el  valenciano) el seseo y ceceo andaluz deriva de la diferente evolución que tuvieron en el norte y sur de España el sistema de sibilantes del español antiguo en torno al siglo XVI. Ambas variantes dialectales, al ser únicamente orales,  han acabado considerándose un castellano moderno "mal pronunciado" pero los andaluces siempre (desde a Reconquista cristiana, obviamente) han hablado español, nunca el actual castellano (conste que me resultaría indiferente usar "castellano" por "español" si no estuviera distinguiendo dialectos).

En cuanto a las causas del seseo en América, solo hay que ver lo mucho que se parecen hablando un canario y un cubano, o un andaluz a un chileno, para intuirlas.

En Canarias predomina el seseo porque los colonizadores españoles eran sobre todo andaluces, y en América pasó otro tanto, de modo que allí donde los andaluces no llevaron directamente su típico seseo, lo hicieron  los canarios (fundamentalmente por el Caribe).

Comment: He leído que la pronunciación chilena y la andaluza del español se parecen debido a que los conquistadores que llegaron aquí eran de origen mayoritariamente andaluz.

Comment: Y resulta curioso que a los españoles en algunas partes de Sudamérica se les haya otorgado el mote de gallegos.

Comment: La emigración gallega fue intensa en algunos países sudamericanos, pero mucho más tardía. Así que cuando comenzaron a llegar en masa, su deje gallego rápidamente los identificaba como españoles, mientras los andaluces aún podían pasar por sudamericanos (o al menos, su acento aún resultaba muy familiar). Supongo que eso fue suficiente para que se sustituyera la parte por el todo.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede encontrar un [documento](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/thesaurus/pdf/07/TH_07_123_123_0.pdf) en el [Centro Virtual Cervantes](http://cvc.cervantes.es/) que expone el origen del ceceo y lo remonta al s. XVI. En dicho [documento](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/thesaurus/pdf/07/TH_07_123_123_0.pdf) se apunta como causa la [indulgencia](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=WEIQMnLRdDXX2AcRurkF) de las familias a la hora de corregir a los hijos y de su penetración en apenas medio siglo.

Dado que la indulgencia es un fenómeno global, entendido como término opuesto a una zona geográfica determinada, es difícil entender porqué se propagó en Andalucía y no en otras zonas. Si bien, parece razonable que, cual mutación genética se tratara, se pueda dar en otras zonas pero por falta de un caldo de cultivo adecuado, no se propague o perdure.

Tan extenso, y documentado artículo, no ahonda en las razonas últimas que crearon ese *caldo de cultivo* pero bien podemos entenderlo como una confluencia de factores indeterminados en el espacio y en el tiempo y que se debiera analizar en términos de historia, demografía, política y sociedad.

Answer (score 1):

Es importantísimo informarse antes de pronunciarse. Aquí os dejo una aclaración, lo que explica que los andaluces y canarios influyeran en la población americana.
Respecto a la leyenda del rey,

> esa es, en efecto, una explicación que  se oye a menudo en los Estados
>   Unidos de América. Se trata de una  leyenda etimológica traída 
>   demasiado por los pelos y que carece  totalmente de fundamento.
>
> Quienes creen que los castellanos  distinguen la "z" y la "s" a  causa
>   de este presunto mandado real,  cometen un doble error:  el primero
>   que para cumplirlo tendrían  que haber convertido en "z" no sólo 
>   palabras como "caza" o "liza", sino  también otras que como "casa" o
>   "lisa"  deberían haber perdido ese  sonido "s". El segundo error es no
>   darse  cuenta de que, en materia de pronunciación,  los pueblos, que
>   son muy suyos, no  suelen acatar fácilmente las órdenes que  les
>   vienen de arriba, aunque no sean tan  absurdas como la presente: en
>   Francia se  impuso en tiempos de la Revolución la  pronunciación "muá
>   le roi" para lo que  escribimos así: "moi le roi", que ni todo  el
>   poder de la Restauración pudo  reconvertir –como se dice  ahora- a la
>   antigua pronunciación: ç "moé le roé"; con excepción,  claro está, de
>   El Canadá francófono,  donde no había prendido  esa innovación
>   revolucionaria.
>
> En la Edad Media se distinguían dos  tipos de "eses" fricativas,  una
>   sonora y otra sorda (que se  escribían con "s" y "ss": "rosa" 
>   –pronunciada como el el catalán  "casa" o el francés "maison"-  y
>   "viniesse"), y dos de "eses" africadas,  también sonora y sorda  (que
>   se escribían respectivamente con  "z" y "ç": "pozo" y "braço"  y se
>   pronunciaban [podso] y [bratso]).  Estos cuatro sonidos se 
>   convirtieron a finales de la Edad Media  en dos, en gran parte  del
>   norte de la Península Ibérica  (la "s" y la "z"), mientras  que en
>   gran parte de Andalucía se  transformaron en un solo sonido  (una "s"
>   que no era exactamente igual  que la castellana).  Fueron dos caminos
>   diferentes los que  siguieron con respecto  a estos sonidos en el
>   norte peninsular  y en Andalucía.
>
> No creemos necesario dilatarse en  más explicaciones con  respecto a
>   algo que, por lo demás,  ha sido cuidadosamente  estudiado por los
>   lingüistas, desde  Rufino José Cuervo.  Quien esté interesado en
>   profundizar  en este asunto, puede  empezar a saciar su curiosidad
>   acudiendo  a libros como los  de J. A. Frago ("Historia de las hablas 
>   andaluzas", Madrid:  Arco/libros, 1993) y J. L. Rivarola,  "La
>   formación lingüística de Hispanoamérica",  Lima, 1990, p. 28).

[El origen de la pronunciación de la z (Moderadora del Foro del hispanista)](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=123#459)

Comment: Bienvenido/a a Spanish.SE. También es importantísimo dar reconocimiento a las fuentes a las que acudes. No pasa nada por copiar y pegar, pero proporciona el enlace al original. Además, [este hilo del CVC](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=123#Arriba) es todo interesante, no solo la parte que has copiado y puede interesarle al resto de usuarios.

Answer (score -2):

En Argentina, cuando pronunciamos la letra "z" la pronunciamos como la letra "s"; sin embargo, la pronunciación "sh" no se da en toda Argentina *como algunos creen*; esto solamente en Buenos Aires, Rosaro (provincia) de Santa Fe Argentina, etc.

La pronunciación "sh" se realiza juntando suavemente las dentaduras superior e inferior *como fuera a morder*.

*NOTA: Mi respuesta está basada en experiencias personales.*

Answer (score -3):

Según un cuento de mi vecino, lo cual más tarde confirmó mi novia(mexicana), tiene raíces en un rey que hablaba con ceceo. Le daba tanta pena por su impedimento y la gente le amaba tanto que la población se puso a imitarlo.

Rey Carlos algo creo

Obviamente dudo su veracidad pero dado que ese acento se encuentra mas común en Madrid y su alrededor siempre lo he considerado una explicación adecuada. (Madrid es donde se encuentra el palacio)

Ni modo que no sea la verdad verdadera se me hace muy tierno :)

Comment: Nunca lo había escuchado, jeje. Pienso que simplemente en el sur de España se perdió el sonido "zeta" y pasó a ser "ese", es decir, se empezó a sesear.

Comment: en realidad no se perdió realmente. Me parece que se mezclo totalmente, igual que el sonido "ch" que es diferente del "original" castellano.

Comment: Yo tambien he oido ese "cuento"

Comment: También lo oí pero es un mito, se puede ver (en ingles) aquí http://linguistlist.org/issues/11/11-2186.html

Comment: lo del rey es absurdo, no entiendo como puede calar. Si fuera cierto en España la s se pronunciaría como th.

Comment: Ningun cuento es 100% cierto, por eso la palabra en si es sinonimo de fabula, mito, chisme etc. Ahorita ando con una de andalucia y cuando se lo conte de broma tambien me dijo que es un cuento reconocido.

Answer (score -3):

La distinción que hacemos en España entre los sonidos de la S y la C-Z es para evitar faltas ortográficas.

Si se aprende a pronunciar con distinción es imposible tener faltas a la hora de escribir "hacer" y "a ser" por poner sólo un ejemplo.

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta confunde causa y efecto. No se "mantienen" letras distintas para respetar una ortografía, sino que el ortografía es un conjunto de reglas para la escritura de una lengua.

Comment: @Diego, en efecto: la ortografía *sigue* a la pronunciación, y no viceversa. El lenguaje escrito es una codificación del habla.