# What are the three systems of pronouncing "c"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, españa, pronunciación, ceceo-seseo

I had some trouble understanding [a question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/7085/9385) that asks for a recommendation of which of three pronunciation systems to learn: *seseo, ceceo,* or *distinción*.  I'm confused because I thought that in Spain, there is a sound similar to the TH in the English word "with," and I thought it was written with Z, CE and CI.  (I thought that CA, CO, CU and final C, called "hard C," as in "*caro*," would be the same the world over.)  But with each new thing I read I've only felt less enlightened.  I think our site needs a clear explanation of the three systems.

There is already [an answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23580/9385) with some nice maps, but audio examples would be appreciated.  Also, is there a universal pronunciation of the word "ceceo"?

Answer (score 5):

The three systems you mention not only relate to how *z/c* is pronounced, but also to how *s* is pronounced.

Consider the words *casa* (house) and *caza* (hunt). There is a group of Spanish speakers that pronounce them *exactly the same*. There is another group that pronounce them differently. This last group is the one that makes a *distinction* between *s* and *z*, and that's why it is labeled ***distinción***. This group uses the sound /s/ for *casa* and the sound /θ/  for *caza* (this last sound is the one you mention to be similar to the TH in the English word "with").

The group that doesn't distinguish between *casa* and *caza* can be further divided in two, according to the sound they use to pronounce both words. The ones that use the sound /s/ for both are labeled ***seseo***. The ones that use the sound /θ/ for both are labeled ***ceceo***.

Finally, in all three systems *ce* and *ci* will use the same sound as *za*, *zo*, *zu*.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a table that I think should boil things down to the most simple:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━┓
┃    type    ┃   S   │CE/CI/Z┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━┫  │ Where
┃ distinción ┃  /s/  │  /θ/  ┃  │ /s/ is like English S
┠────────────╂───────┼───────┨  │     as in [s]ing
┃   seseo    ┃  /s/  │  /s/  ┃  │ /θ/ is like English TH 
┠────────────╂───────┼───────┨  │     as in [th]istle
┃   ceceo    ┃  /θ/  │  /θ/  ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━┛
```

The majority of Spanish speakers in Spain and Equatorial Guinea speak with **distinción**, that is, they distinguish the Z and soft C from the S.  This doesn't mean, as it might sound to English ears that they speak better, just that they literally *distinguish* the two sounds.  For someone from Madrid, *caza* sounds like what in English would be *catha* but *casa* instead is like *cassa*.

The overwhelming majority of Spanish speakers, though, including virtually all speakers from Latin America, are **seseantes**. That means they say pronounce words like *caza* and *casa*, or *cocer* and *coser* identically **and** when they pronounce them, the Z, soft C, and S sound like the English S.  In other words, they pronounce *caza* and *casa* like someone from Spain would pronounce *casa*.  (hence *seseo*, or using *S*)

A minority of Spanish speakers situated in South Spain, are **ceceantes** (there are also a few small pocket areas in Latin America that are too).  They, like *seseantes* pronounce *caza* and *casa* the same.  But the sound they use for the second consonant much more closely matches the one that someone from the North would use to pronounce *caza*.  Technically, the sound is [s̪̟], but it's close enough that the term *ceceo* developed.

---

All of this came about because in the 13-16th century or so, there were a lot more sounds that were very similar and started getting confused and merged.  As a result, even back then before all of the sibilant readjustment had completed they had multiple terms for pronunciations that didn't distinguish: *seseo* (as [s̺]), *çeçeo* (as [t͡s]) and *zezeo* (as [d͡z]].

I'm not entirely sure how someone pronounces the actual word *ceceo* outside of Spain, but my guess is that they pronounce it with the /θ/ sound, or the closest approximation they can so it's clear they're not saying *seseo* (and since the word is literally to talk about the sound used in speech, it's justifiable to use an otherwise foreign sound).

Comment: You're probably using "virtually" right -- but this is word that often gets interpreted differently than I think you meant it.  What would you say to replacing it with "practically" or "very nearly" or something like that?  It felt abrupt when I reached the part about the small pockets.

Comment: Question about the bottom row of the table -- which is amazing, could you post on our Meta the steps you go through to make that?  Maybe you use a utility?  Are you saying that putting the theta symbol in both of those cells is a bit of an oversimplification?  I read at one of the related questions that some people do something interesting with the S.  I think I have come across this in some Spanish films.  It kind of reminded me of one of the sounds of Polish. // Is there a universal pronunciation of *ceceo* (the word)?  Or should I post that as a separate question?

Comment: @aparente001 Virtually for me means "nearly/almost all".  I'm not aware of another interpretation for it? I'm using /θ/ (phonetic) to try to keep it as simple and obvious as possible.If the only difference was [θ] vs [s̻~s̺] vs [s̪̟] (phonemic), I think that would just confuse people more ;-) s̪̟ sounds most like θ (and is so perceived by *seseo* and *distinción* speakers) which is why it traditionally gets that phoneme to represent it. Here we get into the trouble of describing the language phonetically vs phonemically which I tried to avoid because my answer would be 3x as long otherwise.

Comment: Re *virtually* -- I'm not the only one who can get thrown off by that.  For example, Merriam Webster has a second meaning listed: "For all practical purposes, e.g. *virtually unknown*." // So, am I understanding correctly, that the theta appearing in both cells in that row is a slight oversimplification?

Comment: @aparente001 simplification in the sense that it's not *exactly* the same sound as the /θ/ you hear in Madrid. Its technical IPA symbol uses S as the base letter, but the difference between s̪̟ and θ is as slight as is the difference between s̻ and s̻ (the two S sounds used in the Spanish speaking world, that although distinct, no one perceives as representing different letters/sounds).  As a result, Spanish speakers *perceive* it as /θ/, although its evolution is distinct.

Comment: Getting any deeper unfortunately requires a lot of explanation of the difference between phonemic and phonetic transcription and representation as it relates to Spanish sibilants and that could be its own question or three.

Comment: Well, I did come across a question that focused on that, which is why I'm asking.  I'm not asking for more detail than you already provided; I'm just asking if, strictly speaking, that last row is a slight oversimplification.  I *think* that's what your answer was implying, but I wanted to double-check.

Comment: Maybe?  It's both an simplification (the sound isn't identically to the one used in *distinción* dialects) but also simultaneously either an intentional complication or a gross oversimplifcation (speaking strictly, the phoneme should be either /s/ **or** /s/~/θ/, which of course doesn't help us at all).

Comment: @Guifa - minor correction, historic use of the terms *çeçeo* and *zezeo* referred to **orthographic** 'errors' (*ç* in place of *ss*, and *z* in place of *s* respectively). They didn't refer to pronunciations like *ceceo/seseo* today. Source: [*A History of the Spanish Language*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3P8LBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT143&lpg=PT143&dq=çeçeo)

Comment: @ukemi hmm, ç/ss did not have the same pronunciation though. Unfortunately I cannot view the book. I'll link to the article

Answer (score 2):

There are dialects of Spanish that have two [fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricative_consonant) [sibilant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant) phonemes, and there other dialects that have only one.

The dialects that have two fricative sibilants are said to have *distinción*. They have a dental fricative /θ/ and an alveolar fricative /s/. The alveolar /s/ might be realized in varying ways, mostly laminal (the blade of the tongue touches the alveoli) or apical (the apex or tip of the tongue touches the alveoli). *Distinción* with an apical /s/ is the norm in Madrid.

Among the dialects that have only one fricative sibilant, there are some which realize it as a dental /θ/, and others which realize it as an alveolar fricative /s/. The former dialects are called *ceceantes* and are found mostly in southern Spain. The latter are *seseantes* and are found in parts of southern Spain and all over Latin America. For the most part the /s/ among Latin American *seseantes* is a laminal sibilant, though there are dialects (mostly in the Bolivian Andes and northwestern Argentina) where it is apical instead.

[image: Simplified pronunciation table with examples]

Now, the orthography. For dialects with *distinción*, the alveolar sibilant /s/ is always written «s», and the dental sibilant /θ/ is written «z» before «a, o, u» and «c» before «e, i» (there are no «ze, zi» spellings in Spanish except on borrowings like *zeppelin* or *zip*, some learned words like *enzima*, and [a few others](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17600/if-certain-words-undergo-a-spelling-change-from-z-to-c-in-order-to-preserve/25713#25713)). Conversely, if you hear /θ/ in a Spanish dialect with *distinción*, you can always confidently write it down with a «z» or «c» as just explained.

For dialects with *seseo* or *ceceo*, there is no way to know *a priori* if a word you hear with a fricative sibilant is written with a «z/c» or «s». This is of course the cause of many orthographic mistakes, some of which might also produce homonyms. (Many bad jokes have been made based on the homonymy of *casar[se]* "to marry" and *cazar* "to hunt". Also, in Latin American Spanish we tend to say *cocinar* instead of *cocer* "to cook" because *cocer* sounds the same as *coser* "to sew".)

I'm not sure if you meant to ask this, but the letter «c» is always "hard" (/k/) before «a, o, u» and before other consonants (except «h»), no exceptions. There's no way to transform it or mark it in any way to make it sound as a sibilant. In several related Romance languages there is what we call *c cedilla* («ç»): thus Catalan *Barça* (the FC Barcelona) pronounced /'barsa/, Portuguese «praça» /'prasa/ "square, plaza", French *façade* /fa'sad/, but Spanish hasn't had a «ç» for centuries. That's precisely why dialects with *distinción* have to employ «z» before «a, o, u».

Comment: `"there are no «ze, zi» spellings in Spanish except on borrowings like zeppelin or zip"` Note: there are [some exceptions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25713/18348) to this.

Comment: What's crazy is (AFAIK) the ç isn't pronounced any differently than the unvocalized S in those languages with the exception parts of northern Portugal where ç/ce/ci/z group is pronounced laminally and the s/ss is pronounced apically.  Spanish just modified the orthography before it got too ingrained :-)

Comment: @ukemi Well spotted, should have said "borrowings, alternative spellings of learned words and a few onomatopoeic words".

Comment: @guifa Really? That's news to me. I thought Portuguese had lost the distinction completely.

Comment: Sigh.  I'm no closer to understanding *ceceo* and *distinción* than I was before.  You guys are having this sophisticated discussion and I'm looking for a *very basic* explanation that doesn't use a lot of technical language. But Pablo, your post looks like it would also be an addition to the site -- could you draft a question to fit the post you wrote?  For my question, I need someone to *start at the beginning* and explain *distinción* to someone who *doesn't understand the term*.

Comment: @pablodf76 it's a small enough region that it's not important to bring up in Portuguese classes ha.  But for example, the people from Viseu will pronounce the S not as a Z, but as something halfway between the Z and J (it's really just a voiced *ese castellana")

Comment: @guifa Doesn't Euskera have that laminal/apical distinction as well?

Comment: @pablod76 it does. Z is laminal and S is apical.