# Is there an accent that pronounces "s" as ⟨θ⟩?

Tags: pronunciación, ceceo-seseo

I have an audiobook (meant for beginners learning Spanish) where the speaker has an accent I don't recognize. I know that in Spain some *z*'s and *c*'s are pronounced like an English *th* (IPA: ⟨θ⟩). But in this audiobook even many *s*'s sound that way to me. For example, he pronounces "está cansado" like "eθtá canθado", or "su sueño" like "θu θueño".

I also heard another word that sounded odd. "tortilla" was pronounced so that the *ll* had a distinct *l* (ell) and *y* sound. Sort of like: *tor-til-ia*.

Perhaps I should upload some audio snippets.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? To me it almost sounds like someone is trying to fake like they are from Spain and doing a bad job of it! If so, I will stop listening to this audiobook.

Comment: In Andalucía, *ceceante* speakers will use [θ] for both /s/ and /θ/.  If you are not used to hearing [ʎ] because you're familiar with *yeísta* dialects (and thus tend to hear [ʝ] for *ll*), it may be an authentic sound.  If you are used to the way a true [ʎ] sounds, then it may indeed be a bad attempt (as [lj] is the most common manifestation of [ʎ] by *yeístas* trying to mimic it).  However, virtually all *ceceantes* are *yeístas*, so the combination on the surface sounds odd.

Comment: Yes, this is called "ceceo" and is done in some parts of the south of Spain. More information in [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26/24236).

Comment: What you are describing is "seseo" and "yeismo"

Answer (score 2):

So this does not go unanswered here are some references.

[The DPD gives a brief explanation of ceceo](https://www.rae.es/dpd/ceceo)

> ceceo. Consiste en pronunciar la letra s con un sonido similar al que corresponde a la letra z en las hablas del centro, norte y este de España (→ z, 2a); así, un hablante ceceante dirá [káza] por casa, [zermón] por sermón, [perzóna] por persona. El ceceo es un fenómeno dialectal propio de algunas zonas del sur de España y está mucho menos extendido que el seseo (→ seseo).

The [link to seseo](https://www.rae.es/dpd/seseo) provides a description of the opposite phenomenon.

> seseo. 1. Consiste en pronunciar las letras c (ante e, i) y z con el sonido que corresponde a la letra s (→ s, 2); así, un hablante seseante dirá [serésa] por cereza, [siérto] por cierto, [sapáto] por zapato.

> 2. El seseo es general en toda Hispanoamérica y, en España, lo es en Canarias y en parte de Andalucía, y se da en algunos puntos de Murcia y Badajoz. También existe seseo entre las clases populares de Valencia, Cataluña, Mallorca y el País Vasco, cuando hablan castellano, y se da asimismo en algunas zonas rurales de Galicia. El seseo meridional español (andaluz y canario) y el hispanoamericano gozan de total aceptación en la norma culta.

There is more detail about the historical development of these in the [Wikipedia article on development of sibilants in Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_de_las_sibilantes_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol)

There is a separate issue about the pronunciation of -ll- which is covered in the [Wikipedia article on yeismo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye%C3%ADsmo). The article has maps of the distribution of the distinct sounds. It also covers the pronunciation in Rioplatense as zheismo.