# Am I hearing a “z” sound?

Tags: pronunciación

I’ve done a lot of digging to find out whether an “s” in Spanish can ever come off sounding like a “z”. Everything I’m reading suggests that’s not the case. But I feel like I’ve heard certain words containing the “z” instead. For instance, when I hear native Spanish speakers say the last name Torres, it sounds like “Tor-ehz” and not “Tor-eys”. Similarly, when I hear the name Robles, I hear “Rob-lehz”. So, am I hearing things? How should these names be pronounced? Do words that end in “s” often come off sounding like a “z”? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I meant like an English z - a voiced sibilant. Can you explain what you mean when you say that there are slight variations of the Spanish s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's difficult to know exactly how you perceive the sound of *s* in these words, it's entirely possible that it sounds (approximately) like [z] (the English *z*, a [voiced alveolar fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_alveolar_fricative)), or that is has acoustic qualities that register in your ear like [z].

In Spanish /s/ is a rather solitary [phoneme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme), because Spanish doesn't distinguish between voiced and voiceless fricatives (as in the English pairs /f/ vs. /v/, /s/ vs. /z/, *th* as in *thin* and *th* as in *then*, or *sh* as in *show* and *s* as in *vision*). Since the Spanish /s/ doesn't have a voiced counterpart, it doesn't matter if you pronounce it [s] or [z]. Usually it's [s], but in certain environments some speakers may produce [z]. Native Spanish speakers won't usually hear the difference.

This happens independently of other variations in the pronunciation of /s/. Spanish has a lot of dialects and [/s/ is one of the most variable sounds](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1/in-what-ways-is-the-letter-s-or-the-s-sound-pronounced-in-spain?rq=1), so it shouldn't surprise you to [find it pronounced](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20995/the-castilian-spanish-s-pronounced-as-kind-of-sh) differently from the standard that you've been taught. (For example, and in contrast to what you've heard, in my dialect it's very common to turn final /s/ into a barely audible [h] or to drop it altogether.)